# Get latest date from table with their line in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables: **Asset** and **Inventory**.

Table Asset

[image]

Table Inventory

[image]

When I run the following mysql query:

```
SELECT a.assetnum,a.description,a.user,MAX(b.invdate) as invdate , b.note 
FROM asset a 
LEFT JOIN inventory b on a.assetnum=b.assetnum 
GROUP BY a.assetnum, a.description
```

I get is this:

[image]

but, it should be like this....

[image]

Whats wrong with my mysql query? Can somebody help me...

Comment: FROM asset a , something missing in here.

Comment: For correct database work all tables need to have primary key

Comment: Your own data is wrong.... You are saying you want last date well that is the 20th, and as shown in your table inventory the 20th has not good as not, where does the good come from all of a sudden

Comment: @Tomm latest date is correct, but from my query, it will take good as 1st line in inventory table. it should be take not good from 3rd and 4th line of inventory table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basicaly get a random `note` in the result. You probably need something like this:

```
 select a.assetnum,a.description,a.model, i.invdate, i.note 
 from inventory i
 join
 (
   select assetnum, max(invdate) max_invdate
   from inventory
   group by assetnum
 ) t on i.assetnum = t.assetnum and
        i.invdate = t.max_invdate
 right join asset a on a.assetnum = i.assetnum
```

Comment: thanks... its almost work. i also want ghi789 show 'null' in result even though did not have invdate value in inventory table.

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd yes, corrected. You are wellcome :)

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd I have added outer join (`LEFT JOIN`) in order to include also null values in your result. I there something wrong with the current solution?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to support your try and good to try it also:

```
SELECT a.assetnum,
    MAX(a.description) AS description,
    MAX(a.user) AS user,
    MAX(b.invdate) as invdate, 
    (SELECT i.note FROM inventory i 
     WHERE i.invdate = MAX(b.invdate) AND i.assetnum=a.assetnum) note
FROM asset a 
LEFT JOIN inventory b on a.assetnum=b.assetnum 
GROUP BY a.assetnum
```